# cut but keep last delimiter?

Tags: bash, cut

I have `echo "/home/user/test/folder" | cut -d'/' -f4-` give:

```
test/folder
```

But I want to keep the last delimiter, expected result would be:

```
/test/folder
```

how to achieve with `cut`?

Comment: Does it have to be cut? Using bash builtins can be faster. sed (portable) or gnu grep would be more obvious.

Comment: Probably get `sed` involve to solve, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using just bash builtins

```
strip_slashes(){
   declare -n stripped=$1
   local -i i      
   stripped=$3
   for((i=0;i<$2;i++)) ; do
       stripped=${stripped#*/}
   done
   stripped="/$stripped"
}
```

This is invoked as

```
strip_slashes X 3 "/home/user/test/folder"
echo $X
```

The first parameter is the name of the variable to hold the result, then the number of slashes to remove, and the the value to remove them from.

Passing the name of the variable to hold the result means you don't need to either hard code the name (e.g. REPLY as used by select and read by default) nor need a subshell. After the `declare -n` `stripped` is an alias for the named variable.

sed solutions. Using gnu sed

```
echo /home/user/test/folder | sed -E 's:(/[^/]*){2}::'
```

more portable

```
echo /home/user/test/folder | sed 's:/[^/]*/[^/]*::'
```

Comment: I choose this as answer because it give more general solution of `sed`, we can't solve it with just `cut` anyway. other solutions also work.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `/home/user/test/folder` is the contents of some variable `dirpath`, and that the current user's home directory, as given by `$HOME`, is `/home/user`, then the following code would print `Path under $HOME directory is "/test/folder"`.

```sh
dirpath=/home/user/test/folder
printf 'Path under $HOME directory is "%s"\n' "${dirpath#$HOME}"
```

It does this by removing the `$HOME` prefix string from `$dirpath` by means of a standard parameter expansion.

This can be generalised to other paths than those under `$HOME`:

```sh
dirpath=/0/1/2/somewhere/output/test/folder
topdir=${dirpath%/*/*}
printf 'The path under "%s" is "%s"\n' "$topdir" "${dirpath#$topdir}"
```

This would print `The path under "/0/1/2/somewhere/output" is "/test/folder"`.

The value for `topdir` is given by deleting whatever matches `/*/*` from the end of `$dirpath` using a standard parameter substitution.  The pattern `/*/*` should match exactly that which we later want to find at the end of `$dirpath`, in this case the last two components of the `$dirpath` pathname.

After finding `$topdir`, we just repeat the exercises as we did when this top-most directory was `$HOME`.

Comment: Nice! What it would be in `zsh` instead of `bash`?

Comment: @TuyenPham This would work in `zsh` as well. It uses nothing that is specific to `bash`, just basic `sh`-compatible things.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the delimiter, there's nothing intrinsically wrong with adding it back on again.

```
path="/$(echo "/home/user/test/folder" | cut -d'/' -f4-)"
echo "$path"
```